# Viewing IP in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to view ip address in highcharts

[example code](http://jsfiddle.net/LKm6b/1/)

I need to fix yAxis labels and tooltips

current output:

```
       5G    +-------------------+
             |                   |
       3G    |  o        o       |
             |      o            |
 ips         |                   |
             |  o           o    |
             |                   |
       0G    +-------------------+
             0         4k       8k
                     ports
```

output i need:

```
        255.255.255.255 +-------------------+
                        |                   |
                        |  o        o       |
                        |      o            |
 ips    127.0.0.1       |                   |
                        |  o           o    |
                        |                   |
        0.0.0.0         +-------------------+
                        0        4000      8000
                                ports
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [label formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter)

```
yAxis: {
        labels: {
                 formatter: function () {
                      return num2ip(this.value);
                 }
        }
}
```

You can format tooltip as follows, the catch is to use `this.key` to reference the third value in the bubble plot

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return '<b>' + num2ip(this.y) + ':' + this.x + '</b> - <b>' + this.key + '</b>' ;                    
    }
},
```

[Demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKm6b/4/)

Comment: @seyed that's already answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991335/highcharts-tooltip-formatter just use the value in the formatter

Answer (score -1):

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PC2QA/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            inverted: true
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1.1.1.1 ', '2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```