# How to add tooltip on the render image in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to add a tool tip on the render image. I tried to add tooltip on the render image but it says "tooltip is not a function". http://jsfiddle.net/bangkalog/gh7cbx86/

```
chart.renderer.image('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png').add().tooltip({
        formatter: function () {
            return 'Test';
        }
})
```

Comment: Hi Reyan, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16991335/highcharts-tooltip-formatter may be it helps you. thanks

Comment: thank you @vekay but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Hi Reynan. Are you trying to add a custom formatter to the existing chart's tooltip, or do you want to add a tooltip to the image of the sun, rather than the chart itself?

Comment: @ChrisHG yes correct I am trying to add tool tip on the sun image.

Answer (score 2):

Tooltip works well with all functionalities only on points or series features.
So if you want to use formatter callback the easiest way is to render your image as a point.

```
{
    showInLegend: false,
  data: [{
    x: 0.5,
    y: 200,
    marker: {
      symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
    }
  }]
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qpat08sw/

However, it is possible to render a custom tooltip for images, but note that formatter callback doesn't work and some deeper changes are needed.

```
function(chart) { // on complete

var img = chart.renderer.image('http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png', 100, 100, 30, 30).on('mouseover', function(e) {
    var label = chart.tooltip.getLabel();

    chart.tooltip.move(80, 60);
    label.attr({
      text: 'custom tooltip'
    });
  })
  .add();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tvepjk9g/